# Нужно перед каждым элементом строки '!' ставить элемент ',' php

Tags: php

Нужно перед каждым элементом строки  '!' ставить элемент ','  php

Comment: Ставьте, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
$replacedStr = str_replace('!', ',!', $your_string);
```

Comment: на данном сайте не принято отвечать на вопросы-домашки. домашна на сленге — задание с отсутствующим решением со стороны автора вопроса

Comment: @return, вполне нормальный вопрос. И ответ - тоже.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не знаю, какой смысл засорять сайт вопросами, ответы на которые можно найти в гугле. у PHP уже есть база знаний по PHP — это его документация. если и с ней что-то не понятно, просто приходите сюда и говорите именно про этот момент, а не про то, как сделать замену подстрок.